# Converting a text file into String array with regular expression

Tags: android, regex, android-studio

I have a .txt file which contains above 1000 words

```
sample city names below
```

Razvilka
Moscow
Firozpur Jhirka
Kathmandu
Kiev
Pokhara
Merida
Delhi
Reshetnikovo
Ciudad Bolivar
Marfino
Zhukovskiy
Reutov
Kurovskoye
etc

I would like to have these words in this format below

```
"Razvilka","Moscow","etc","etc"
```

enclosed with double quotation and with a comma in the end.I am using Notepad++.Could you mention how to do it and which software should I use it?

Comment: Avinash could you mention it in details ? noob here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Notepad++, make a **Search and Replace** replacing

```
\b(\w+)\b
```

with

```
"$1",
```

It'll find all words and replace with them self, surrounded by quotes. You'll have to manually remove the last `,` if that's unwanted.

Regards

Comment: Thanks, that is what I was looking for.Cheers.

Comment: but if this was what You needed, it was not programming related question, isn´t it?

Comment: there is a "-(dash)" before in some words.  eg:    -"etc",    how do I care about that ?

Comment: If it always is in the beginning `(-?\b\w+)\b` if you want to keep the dash.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if this question is about programming, but You tagged android, regex and android studio, so I guess it is. If yes, You can simply `split` a `string` in that way:

```
String[] splitted = yourString.split("\\s+");
```

In that case, You are splitting the `strings` by whitespaces (this `regex` is also for more than one whitespace), like Your `string` seems to be. If You have more than one `delimiter`, You can do it by using the `OR operator |`

```
String[]splitted = yourString.split("-|\\.");
```

In that example, You are splitting the String by `-` and `.` (minus and point). The `delimiter` is the sign where the String is splitted by.